# htaccess caching for specific file extensions?

Tags: performance, .htaccess, http-headers, yslow

I'm trying to optimize my site using yslow and I scored an F for "Add Expires Headers" I currently have my index page set to no-cache for users logging in so my question is, is it possible to add a filematch for other file types like images, css, and js to my htaccess file?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"/> <!-- Important for security -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1"/>
```

If so will this impact or override my no-cache setting?

Thanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of the section that starts "Never Expire" Policy in Chapter 3 of the Book of Speed - http://www.bookofspeed.com/chapter3.html